# Unexpected signal during runtime execution in Go lang

Tags: go, google-app-engine-golang

I am getting this error in Go after running my program for around 25 mins still.i am using the library like gorobotn ,sqlite to save the data and one more screentshots library.

in ubuntu i am using go version of 1.14.6. but in windows i am not facing this issue.only in the ubuntu i am facing the above issue suddenly i amg getting this error.

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
            [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x7fec775813aa]

        
        runtime stack:
        runtime.throw(0xde017b, 0x2a)`enter code here`
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1116 +0x72
        runtime.sigpanic()
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:679 +0x46a

  goroutine 192 [select, 28 minutes]:
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc000f205a0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2099 +0x99e
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1647 +0xc56

goroutine 147 [select, 29 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionResetter(0xc0002ac3c0, 0xf68860, 0xc000e502c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1065 +0xfb
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:723 +0x193

goroutine 148 [select, 29 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc0002ac6c0, 0xf68860, 0xc000e50500)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1052 +0xe8
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:722 +0x15d

goroutine 149 [select, 29 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionResetter(0xc0002ac6c0, 0xf68860, 0xc000e50500)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1065 +0xfb
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:723 +0x193

goroutine 157 [syscall, 29 minutes]:
github.com/robotn/gohook._Cfunc_start_ev()
    _cgo_gotypes.go:124 +0x41
created by github.com/robotn/gohook.Start
    /home/karthik/go/src/github.com/robotn/gohook/hook.go:224 +0x67

goroutine 144 [select, 29 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc000fa8240, 0xf68860, 0xc000e94d00)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1052 +0xe8
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:722 +0x15d

goroutine 187 [select, 28 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionResetter(0xc000fa8480, 0xf68860, 0xc000d2af40)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1065 +0xfb
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:723 +0x193

goroutine 186 [select, 28 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc000fa8480, 0xf68860, 0xc000d2af40)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1052 +0xe8
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:722 +0x15d

goroutine 156 [select, 29 minutes]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc0000ae240)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2277 +0x11c
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1648 +0xc7b

goroutine 200 [select, 27 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc000fa8540, 0xf68860, 0xc000bb4d80)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1052 +0xe8
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:722 +0x15d

goroutine 160 [select, 29 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc0002ac9c0, 0xf68860, 0xc000e50bc0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1052 +0xe8
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:722 +0x15d

goroutine 161 [select, 29 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionResetter(0xc0002ac9c0, 0xf68860, 0xc000e50bc0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1065 +0xfb
created by database/sql.OpenDB
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:723 +0x193

goroutine 1295 [chan send]:
github.com/BurntSushi/xgb.(*Conn).generateSeqIds(0xc0013afef0)
    /home/karthik/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/xgb.go:278 +0x73
created by github.com/BurntSushi/xgb.postNewConn
    /home/karthik/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/xgb.go:131 +0x1c2

goroutine 1294 [chan send]:
github.com/BurntSushi/xgb.(*Conn).generateXIds(0xc0013afef0)
    /home/karthik/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/xgb.go:253 +0x9e
created by github.com/BurntSushi/xgb.postNewConn
    /home/karthik/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/xgb.go:130 +0x1a0

goroutine 1308 [chan send]:
github.com/BurntSushi/xgb.(*Conn).generateSeqIds(0xc001324000)
    /home/karthik/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/xgb.go:278 +0x73
created by github.com/BurntSushi/xgb.postNewConn
    /home/karthik/go/src/github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/xgb.go:131 +0x1c2
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1 signal: false
```

Comment: Is this really _full_ stack printout? I'm asking because a process is sent `SIGSEGV` in the case when it attempted to access an unmapped memory region (the most typical case is trying to read or write memory at address 0 (on x86 and compatibles). But your stack trace looks like if the process received this signal externally. So I would conjure you have heavily redacted the stack trace or did not show the full stack trace.

Comment: Hey it is not the full there were more go routines list printed and I am using ubuntu18.04 actually.

Comment: If you want I can show you the full

Comment: 1) I asked about the exact version of Go used to build the program. This is mostly because you have to look at the source code of the matching version to make sense of the line numbers in the stack dump. 2) I admit you might be not a native English speaker, so here's a friendly nudge: it's a bit weird to put "if you want" in the proposition to show the full stack trace: it is your problem to solve and I am spending my own time trying to solve it. I have made a guess to the problem's cause and made it clear that the provided information is far from being complete to do more educated reasoning…

Comment: …so you might show the full stack trace if _you_ want to take a chance to have your problem solved. Also please note that SO is not really a fitting resource for asking questions like the one we're discussing; you might learn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) why. It's best to ask such questions [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) instead. There are two reasons: 1) Badly-formulated questions like yours have very weak chance of being solved: it is now on the second or third page of the output by tag `go`, so whoever had a chance of seeing it…

Comment: …have already forgot about that. I'm still here because we're in the comment thread, you know. ; 2) Such questions tend to require multiple back-and-forth exchanges to collect all the necessary information. SO has a format absolutely unfit for such exchanges.

Comment: hey i will provide you with that one. yes actaully i am not native speaker but still learning

Comment: OK, let's pretend that you honestly put the whole printout (as it looks like you've just bolted on more text from an unrelated execution—as the «\`enter code here\`» bit from the original version is still there, sadly. But OK, the rest of the stack trace does not hint at what gone awry but form the rest of the question I gather you're using at least three packages which call to library code written in C: an sqlite driver, `github.com/BurntSushi/xgb` and an unnabed package to deal with screenshots.

Comment: Since your program fails because it tried to access memory at address 0x08, which, on x86 systems (and it looks like you're using such system) is usually considered invalid. Unless you do dirty tricks with the `unsafe` library, the culprit is most probably one of those C libraries (or the way you submit your data to them). Unfortunately, without seeing the code, it's almost impossible to analyze the problem further.

Comment: Okay  thank you for the help can you connect to me through phone ? So that I can show you the whole code

Comment: Acutally I want to show you the whole error but the whole error is around 1,30,000 lines so I was unable to show you the whole error.